# Should I use dynamic variables in cache tags?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, best-practice, block-cache, magento-1.14

### TL;DR

Can/should cache tags in Magento be dynamic?

### Background

I'm creating a CMS integration from an external CMS into Magento. The data is stored in Elasticsearch in AWS. I have a custom controller which the page's URL is rewritten to, which uses the URL as a key and loads the data from a custom block I created called `content/dynamic`.

Now I want to add block caching to it.

I know that the pertinent settings here are the cache *tags* and the cache *key*.

I'm thinking of using `Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG` as well as the store as base cache tags, then adding a custom cache tag e.g. `Me_Content_Model_Dynamic::CACHE_TAG`, and the appropriate `<global><cache><types>` entry for that so that I can clear all cached dynamic content from the Cache Management screen in Magento admin.

One of the features I need to implement is to be able to refresh content caches for the `content/dynamic` block for a specific CMS page, as well as any content blocks underneath it.

### Specifics

I'm thinking of adding *another* cache tag that is dynamic, e.g. `dynamic_content_hashofURLhere` to each page's instance of `content/dynamic` and all child blocks of it, so that I can easily identify dynamic page's cache entries for all content relating to a certain page.

### Question

Is this the right way to use the cache tags?

It seems to me to be an easy way to target and invalidate a whole page worth of block cache entries for a page (no matter how many there are) without having to construct the cache *key* for each content block in the page and invalidate them individually.

Are dynamic cache tags used in the Magento code base already?

Is this best practice?

For clarity - I don't want to be able to clear any of the *dynamic cache tags* from the Cache Management page. I'd want to do this programatically. From the Cache Management page I'd only target a static cache tag that I add separately from this dynamic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can/should cache tags in Magento be dynamic?...Is this the right way to use the cache tags?*

**Yes!** This is exactly what cache tags are for - to group a number of cache entries together.

Here are some quotes from various blogs:

> Cache tags exist so that we can selectively clear cache instances.

Source: [Erfan Emani](https://erfanimani.com/magento-block-caching-and-system-config/)

> The `$data` stored in the cache can also be *tagged* with metadata. This allows for logical groupings of cache entries for mass deletion.

Source: [Nick Jones](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/)

---

Presumably having dynamic cache tags would mean that you could end up with hundreds or thousands of cache tags in your cache storage. Whether or not this introduces a performance impact over not having those cache tags would probably require some benchmarking, however in theory it should not introduce a large overhead as the cache tags are not queried unless being cleared for deletion.

Assuming the dynamic cache tag ended up as `dynamic_content_HISUDFHS8y92333` you could easily clear all content block cache entries for the page `HISUDFHS8y92333` like this:

```
/** @var Mage_Core_Model_Cache $cache */
$cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
$cache->clean(array(Me_Content_Model_Dynamic::CACHE_TAG . '_HISUDFHS8y92333'));
```

---

> *Are dynamic cache tags used in the Magento code base already?*

**Yes.**

For a quick example you can take a look at `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::addModelTags()`:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
public function addModelTags(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $model)
{
    $cacheTags = $model->getCacheIdTags();
    if (false !== $cacheTags) {
        $this->addCacheTag($cacheTags);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

If you examine `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::getCacheIdTags` you will see that it returns an array of the existing model's cache tags *with the model's ID appended to the end*:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php
public function getCacheIdTags()
{
    $tags = false;
    if ($this->getId() && $this->_cacheTag) {
        $tags = array();
        if (is_array($this->_cacheTag)) {
            foreach ($this->_cacheTag as $_tag) {
                $tags[] = $_tag.'_'.$this->getId();
            }
        } else {
            $tags[] = $this->_cacheTag.'_'.$this->getId();
        }
    }
    return $tags;
}
```

This method gets called by `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::getCacheTags`, which means that dynamic cache tags are used in any Magento model (that extends from core model abstract) which is cache enabled.

> *Is this best practice?*

Yeah, sure. It's much better than searching the cache storage for keys that match a certain pattern just to delete them all.